# Matplotlib xticks are not printed throughout the x-axis but only to a part of it

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using this code:

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import random
 
df = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx')
time = mdates.drange(dt.datetime(2020, 6, 24, 0, 0, 0), dt.datetime(2020, 10, 9, 0, 0 ,0), dt.timedata(hours = 120))
  
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))
plt.xticks(time)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%m-%d %H:%M"))
ax.plot(df.x, df.y, 'bo-')
ax.set(title='Active Calls', ylabel='Calls', xlabel='Time')
ax.grid()
  
ax.xaxis_date() # Default date formatter
fig.autofmt_xdate()
  
plt.show()
```

2020,6,24 is the 1st timestamp + value of the excel file
2020,10,9 is the ~15000nd timestamp + value of the excel file

However instead of putting xticks throughout whole the x-axis of the plot, it puts them, only to a part. So for example from point 0 on x-axis to the middle of x-axis there is no xtick, from the middle to about the quarter before the end of x-axis there are xticks from 24/6/2020 - 9/10/2020, and from the quarter before the end of x-axis to the end of x-axis there are no xticks. How can this happen?? Any idea?

This is the output:
[image]

With the below commands:

```
 print("dataframe['Date'].min = ", dataframe['Date'].min)
 print("dataframe['Date'].max = ", dataframe['Date'].max)
```

I get this strange answer:

```
dataframe['Date'].min =  <bound method NDFrame._add_numeric_operations.<locals>.min of 0       2020-06-24 12:30:49.999997
1       2020-06-24 12:40:50.000002
2       2020-06-24 12:50:49.999998
3       2020-06-24 13:00:50.000003
4       2020-06-24 13:10:49.999999
                   ...            
15401   2020-09-10 11:20:49.999998
15402   2020-09-10 11:30:50.000003
15403   2020-09-10 11:40:49.999999
15404   2020-09-10 11:50:50.000003
15405   2020-09-10 12:00:50.000000
Name: Date, Length: 15406, dtype: datetime64[ns]>
dataframe['Date'].max =  <bound method NDFrame._add_numeric_operations.<locals>.max of 0       2020-06-24 12:30:49.999997
1       2020-06-24 12:40:50.000002
2       2020-06-24 12:50:49.999998
3       2020-06-24 13:00:50.000003
4       2020-06-24 13:10:49.999999
                   ...            
15401   2020-09-10 11:20:49.999998
15402   2020-09-10 11:30:50.000003
15403   2020-09-10 11:40:49.999999
15404   2020-09-10 11:50:50.000003
15405   2020-09-10 12:00:50.000000
Name: Date, Length: 15406, dtype: datetime64[ns]>
```

Comment: I think attaching a graph at the moment and showing what kind of data it is will bring an early solution to the problem.

Comment: I have updated the post, with the output I get.

Comment: Based on the jumps throughout your figure, are you sure that 2020-06-24 and 2020-10-09 are the minimum and maximum date values in your plot? What is the result of `df.x.min()` and `df.x.max()`?

Comment: @ luuk: I have updated the 1st post.